# A particular IP address stops working on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ip, wireless-router

I have a small network with a cisco linksys E2500 series router and few Access points to help with wider wireless coverage.

Recently, I notice that a particular IP adderess on my network suddenly stop being able to reach the internet.

It can ping every other device on the network, including the default gateway (router), but not the DNS address or any other external/ web address.

Particular IP address: 192.168.1.25/24

Gateway 192.168.1.1

I have a DNS address which has been working perfectly for over 2 years now.

I have restarted my router several times, clearing the DHCP table, restarted all Access points...all to no avail!

When i assign this particular IP address statically to another PC or device, internet service suddenly stops, and that device is unable to ping external addresses; but when i revert to DHCP, the client picks another IP address and surfs the internet.

This is really strange and would require your assistance in resolving this please.

Comment: Have you checked the router configuration? 

Is `192.168.1.25` in / out of the DHCP range?

Comment: It is within the DHCP range. I am leasing from .10 to .250 (making a total of 240 available addresses - .25 inclusive).